# getting an Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, guzzle

I am trying to access an api but unfortunately I am getting an invalid argument.
Below is my code in the view.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Career</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($students as $student)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$student->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->address}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->career}}</td>
      </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

Below is my controller for the students.

```
class StudentController extends ClientController
 {
       public function getAllStudents()
  {
    $students = $this->obtainAllStudents();

  return view('students/all-students', ['students' => $students]);
   }
 }
```

The obtain allAllStudents function is taken from the ClientController class

```
protected function obtainAllStudents()
{
  $this->performGetRequest('https://lumenapi.juandmegon.com/students');


}
```

Comment: please dd($students) your variable so that you can see what you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse data which should be like

```
  return view('students/all-students', ['students' => $students->data]);
```

As much I able to see your response from

```
'https://lumenapi.juandmegon.com/students'
```

you are getting object which contains  array, to traverse array your must first get the object.

Or you can directly use in blade file like

```
@foreach ($students->data as $student)
```

and you haven't return in function

```
protected function obtainAllStudents()
{
//you missed return here
  return $this->performGetRequest('https://lumenapi.juandmegon.com/students');
}
```

Comment: When I add this in the controller `return view('students/all-students', ['students' => $students->data]);`

Comment: I am getting `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: you need to add return in protected function obtainAllStudents() function

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean?

Comment: I have updated the answer please look you missed the return statement,

Comment: Thank you Th3.  I am a numpty!

Comment: At first everyone is :D, just keep trying.